# Struggling with soap request (Siri real time bus monitoring)

Tags: php, soap, siri-xml

I have been trying so hard to build a request to the wsdl service of Siri to get vehicle monitoring, but all my tries have failed so far. I getting to the conclusion where I fail at constructing the parmters.
A successful request should look something like this:
[bahrainbusit.com/request.xml](http://bahrainbusit.com/request.xml)

and the data types as executed by $client->__getTypes();

[bahrainbusit.com/test.txt](http://bahrainbusit.com/test.txt)

Thank you in advance.